# FadeTransition and AnimatedOpacity are not in sync with each other

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

**Minimal reproducible code:**

```
static const Duration _duration = Duration(seconds: 5);
static const Curve _curve = Curves.fastOutSlowIn;
AnimationController _controller;
bool _flag = false;

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _controller = AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: _duration);
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final box = Container(color: Colors.orange, width: 100, height: 100);
  return Scaffold(
    body: Column(
      children: [
        FadeTransition(
          opacity: CurvedAnimation(parent: _controller, curve: _curve),
          child: box,
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 20),
        AnimatedOpacity(
          curve: _curve,
          duration: _duration,
          opacity: _flag ? 1 : 0,
          child: box,
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 20),
        RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              _flag = !_flag;
              if (_flag) {
                _controller.forward();
              } else {
                _controller.reverse();
              }
            });
          },
          child: Text(_flag ? 'Hide' : 'Show'),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

**Output:**

As you can see, both animations are not in sync with one another. I'm using the same `Curve` and `Duration` for both `FadeTransition` and `AnimatedOpacity`. However, if you remove `curve`, the animation sync. So, what am I doing wrong here?

[image]

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I missed the `reverseCurve` parameter.

```dart
FadeTransition(
  opacity: CurvedAnimation(
    parent: _controller,
    curve: _curve,
    reverseCurve: _curve, // Solved the problem. 
  ),
  child: box,
)
```

Answer (score 1):

When you calling _controller.reverse(), FadeTransition uses reversed curve, but AnimatedOpacity is using same curve. You can add FlippedCurve widget to fix it.

And you stop the animation without waiting till the end, controller.reverse, will start moving to opposite direction from the stop point.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  static const Duration _duration = Duration(seconds: 5);
  static const Curve _curve = Curves.fastOutSlowIn;

  AnimationController _controller;
  bool isShowing = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: _duration);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final box = Container(color: Colors.orange, width: 100, height: 100);
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            FadeTransition(
              opacity: CurvedAnimation(parent: _controller, curve: _curve),
              child: box,
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            AnimatedOpacity(
              curve: isShowing ? _curve : FlippedCurve(_curve),
              duration: _duration,
              opacity: isShowing ? 1 : 0,
              child: box,
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  if (isShowing) {
                    _controller.reverse();
                  } else {
                    _controller.forward();
                  }
                  isShowing = !isShowing;
                });
              },
              child: Text(isShowing ? 'Hide' : 'Show'),
            ),
            AnimatedBuilder(
                builder: (_, __) {
                  return Text(
                    _controller.value.toString(),
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  );
                },
                animation: _controller)
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for giving me an idea (+1) . I actually forgot to add the `reverseCurve` parameter. That solved my problem.